# How can I select data from an array in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have an array as structured below:

```
var locations = [
{
    lat: 54.603928, //latitude 
    lon: -5.915033, //longditude
    title: 'Odyssey Arena, Belfast', //name of venue
    html: [ //the HTML that appears inside the map tooltips
        '<h4>Odyssey Arena, Belfast.</h4>', //name of venue
        '<p>23rd March 2015</p>' //date of venue
    ].join(''), //Joins the HTML 
    icon: '//maps.google.com/mapfiles/markerA.png', //the marker for the location on the google map
    zoom: 7//makes the map zoom in closer to the location when clicked
},
{
    lat: 53.347496,
    lon: -6.228508,
    title: 'O2 Arena, Dublin',
    html: [
        '<h4>CO2 Arena, Dublin.</h4>',
        '<p>20th March 2015</p>'
    ].join(''),
    icon: '//maps.google.com/mapfiles/markerB.png',
    zoom: 7
}];
```

I need to extract the `title` value from each and place it in a new array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) method:

```
var newArray = $.map(locations, function(item){
  return item.title;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an associative array, but just an array of objects. You also don't need jQuery.

```
locations.map(function(l){return l.title})
```

Here, i use ES5 [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the `title` property of each array item (not supported IE8 and under).

Comment: Thanks, I noticed after it wasn't an associate array so I quickly edited the title.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++ ) {
    console.log (locations[i].title);
}
```

You can also use for...in statement for iterating through objects.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't notice the "placing into array" part... :(